# Laravel Routing - 404

Tags: laravel, routes

I tried different routes but I am getting 404 on show,edit,store.

```
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/', 'IndexController@index')->name('index')->middleware('user');
Route::get('/user/profile', 'HomeController@index')->name('user')->middleware('user');
Route::get('/{product}/show', 'IndexController@show')->name('product')->middleware('user');

Route::prefix('cart')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', 'IndexController@cart')->name('cart')->middleware('auth');
    Route::get('/{product}/add', 'IndexController@cartAdd')->name('cartAdd')->middleware('auth');
});

Route::prefix('dashboard')->group(function () {
    Route::get('', 'AdminController@index')->name('admin')->middleware('admin');
    Route::get('products', 'ProductController@index')->name('productIndex')->middleware('admin');
    Route::get('products/create', 'ProductController@create')->name('productCreate')->middleware('admin');
    Route::get('products/{product}', 'ProductController@show')->name('productShow')->middleware('admin');
    Route::put('products/{product}', 'ProductController@update')->name('productUpdate')->middleware('admin');
    
    Route::post('products', 'ProductController@store')->name('productStore')->middleware('admin');
    Route::get('products/{product}/edit', 'ProductController@edit')->name('productEdit')->middleware('admin');
    Route::post('products/{product}', 'ProductController@destroy')->name('productDestroy')->middleware('admin');
});
```

I'm trying to fix the routes by rearranging but didn't have any luck so far.

Comment: Also, the cartadd and userprofile also getting 404

Comment: It seems like I fixed by changing it through the controllers. From Product $product I change it to $id instead to find the specific item and it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('/{product}/show', 'IndexController@show')->name('product')->middleware('user');
```

Move this route at the end. Using a dynamic value that soon in a route without any prefix is not the best way to go by the way. Maybe you can prefix it with something static.

Run `php artisan optimize` before testing it, to reconfig cache and routes.

Comment: Tried moving it but still getting 404 on ProductController@show - ProductController@edit - and ProductController@store. I tried php artisan optimze but it gives another error though

Comment: what does the error say? If you can't cache your routes and your cache then it's a thing that should be fixed.

Comment: Do you define middleware to user and admin? If you dont define, change all middleware to `middleware('auth');`

Comment: Unable to prepare route [api/user] for serialization. Uses Closure. <= error. @xNoJustice I am new to laravel but is defining the middleware by creating and using artisan make:middleware right?If so I already made them.

Comment: You have to link their alias with the associated class in Kernel.php as well. About the error remove the logic you have inside the routes and use controllers.

Comment: I already associated it in the kernel and it was working before.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it is because of the route key name here

```
   public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'prod_name';
    }
```

after deleting it all routes are working again.